# SVG loader won't animate properly when there's a heavy background JS load. Is this fixable?

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm using a basic SVG loader while my site does some heavy JS work, but it hardly animates at all.  Can I do something to give it priority in the browser?  I'm very happy for the JS execution to be 0.01s slower if it means the SVG will animate properly.

If I remove the JS from my site the svg animates perfectly, but once the JS is running it barely animates at all.  This is in Chrome 69.

This is the svg file:

```
<svg width="42" height="42" viewBox="0 0 42 42" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<circle cx="5"  cy="5"  r="5" fill-opacity=".8"><animate attributeName="fill-opacity" begin="0s" dur="2s"   values=".8;.1;.8" calcMode="linear" repeatCount="indefinite"/></circle>
<circle cx="5"  cy="21" r="5" fill-opacity=".2"><animate attributeName="fill-opacity" begin="0s" dur="1.8s" values=".1;.8;.1" calcMode="linear" repeatCount="indefinite"/></circle>
<circle cx="5"  cy="37" r="5" fill-opacity=".4"><animate attributeName="fill-opacity" begin="0s" dur="1.6s" values=".8;.1;.8" calcMode="linear" repeatCount="indefinite"/></circle>
<circle cx="21" cy="5"  r="5" fill-opacity=".8"><animate attributeName="fill-opacity" begin="0s" dur="1.4s" values=".1;.8;.1" calcMode="linear" repeatCount="indefinite"/></circle>
<circle cx="21" cy="21" r="5" fill-opacity=".4"><animate attributeName="fill-opacity" begin="0s" dur="1.2s" values=".8;.1;.8" calcMode="linear" repeatCount="indefinite"/></circle>
<circle cx="21" cy="37" r="5" fill-opacity=".2"><animate attributeName="fill-opacity" begin="0s" dur="1.4s" values=".8;.1;.8" calcMode="linear" repeatCount="indefinite"/></circle>
<circle cx="37" cy="5"  r="5" fill-opacity=".4"><animate attributeName="fill-opacity" begin="0s" dur="1.6s" values=".8;.1;.8" calcMode="linear" repeatCount="indefinite"/></circle>
<circle cx="37" cy="21" r="5" fill-opacity=".6"><animate attributeName="fill-opacity" begin="0s" dur="1.8s" values=".8;.1;.8" calcMode="linear" repeatCount="indefinite"/></circle>
<circle cx="37" cy="37" r="5" fill-opacity=".8"><animate attributeName="fill-opacity" begin="0s" dur="2s"   values=".1;.8;.1" calcMode="linear" repeatCount="indefinite"/></circle>
</svg>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I would reconsider js. If this affects basic animation you probably do something wrong. Could it be done without js or maybe in a hidden element? Can you post what are the exact manipulations?

Comment: You should focus on your js. That's where we can help. In a comment you stated you are doing heavy DOM manips on a table. You could do it by batches, powered by an requestAnimationFrame loop so that your graphics can update correctly, also, try to make all that can be done out of the document, to avoid tons of style recalcs. But without having a clear view on what you are doing, hard to help you further.

Comment: On your last point Kaiido - I have visibility:hidden until the manipulations are complete. I'm hoping that means I don't get style recalcs/repaints during the code execution...  Hoping.

Comment: @Codemonkey no, visibilty hidden will just avoid paints of these elements, but reflow will still happen.

Comment: I cba to extract the relevant JS here, but basically I have a dozen tables on a page.  They have visibility hidden (and my svg animation showing) while I do the following: I loop through them all and set cell widths on the first row of each table so that all of the columns line up.  I then examine the width of the tables compared to the width of the viewport and systematically remove the less important columns until it fits.  Once that's all sorted I make the tables visible and remove the loader animation.  The user gets a toggle to show the extra columns if they wish.

Comment: My current "fix" is to abandon svg for this and just use an animated gif instead, which works flawlessly. Simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe [Web Workers](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webworkers.asp) is exactly what you need!

> A web worker is a JavaScript running in the background, without affecting the performance of the page.

You need to extract your heavy js code into it so you can improve page performance.

Comment: I've just had a look and it says you can't do DOM manipulation in a web worker?  My heavy JS load is resizing/hiding columns in a large `<table>`, so I'm not sure it'd work for my use case?  Besides, it seems overkill, is there not a simpler solution?

Comment: One easy solution seems to be to switch the animated svg out for an animated gif, for example.  If a browser can be intelligent enough to keep an animated gif going, why not an svg?  Have I just done something simple wrong?

Comment: Yes. That is true about DOM manipulation. In that case you have to optimize your js code. Another Idea is you may try to do your animation with js (js is sync so you can control what should be done first)

Comment: Yes, Gif is another opportunity. Your SVG is ok for me, just heavy js code may really affect your page performance. Also! Try Performance devtool in google chrome to analyze your js code (if you are not familiar with that tab learn about in on youtube)

Comment: I've upvoted and accepted this even though I've not implemented it, as I'm sure it will help someone somewhere one day!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using [SMIL animations](https://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-smil) you may try CSS animations (better supported)

```css
circle{
 animation:changeOpacity var(--d) infinite
}

@keyframes changeOpacity{
  0%{fill-opacity:var(--a)}
  50%{fill-opacity:var(--b)}
  100%{fill-opacity:var(--c)}
}
```

```html
<svg width="42" height="42" viewBox="0 0 42 42" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<circle cx="5"  cy="5"  r="5" style="--a:.8;--b:.1;--:.8;--d:1.8s"></circle>
<circle cx="5"  cy="21" r="5" style="--a:.1;--b:.8;--:.1;--d:1.8s"></circle>
<circle cx="5"  cy="37" r="5" style="--a:.8;--b:.1;--:.8;--d:1.6s"></circle>
<circle cx="21" cy="5"  r="5" style="--a:.1;--b:.8;--:.1;--d:1.4s"></circle>
<circle cx="21" cy="21" r="5" style="--a:.8;--b:.1;--:.8;--d:1.2s"></circle>
<circle cx="21" cy="37" r="5" style="--a:.8;--b:.1;--:.8;--d:1.4s"></circle>
<circle cx="37" cy="5"  r="5" style="--a:.8;--b:.1;--:.8;--d:1.6s"></circle>
<circle cx="37" cy="21" r="5" style="--a:.8;--b:.1;--:.8;--d:1.8s"></circle>
<circle cx="37" cy="37" r="5" style="--a:.8;--b:.1;--:.8;--d:2s"></circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: If SMIL doesn't animate properly because of js execution, I fear CSS transitions will suffer the same. (Beside, support for CSS transition on SVG element is not great either).

Comment: I've now tried this approach, it made no real difference.